# In Access is it possible to close a variable from a global function?

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, save, global

In my access program I am going to ask the user every time they close the program if they want to save. This can be done from any form. The problem arises as I want to create a global function in order to cut down on repetitive code. How would this be done?? In a class module? (How is that set up??)

If it helps my code is as follows;

```
If Me.Dirty Then
 Dim LResponse As Integer

 LResponse = MsgBox("You have unsaved changes. Do you really want to close the database", vbYesNo, "Close form")

 If LResponse = vbYes Then
  DoCmd.Close
  Cancel = True
 End If
Else
 DoCmd.CloseDatabase
End If
```

Comment: I'll ask the same questions I asked on your previous question: (1) What does your class do? (2) How is that associated with the form that the user is on? (3) What part of your code is trying to invoke the class' `Close` function? (I get the feeling from a comment that you are trying to close the class when the user tries to close a form.) (4) Is the `Close` function actually in a class, or just in a standard code module?

Answer (score 0):

A bound form will by default save changed data when closed, so you don't need all this.

Thus, all you need is a single code line:

```
DoCmd.Quit
```

If you systematically wish to add features or behaviour to forms or controls, use *WithEvents*.

An example can be found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html).